# Вывод индекса самой длинной строки

Tags: c++, vector

**Задача**: В векторе строк `some_vector` найдите самую длинную строку и её индекс. Выведите её в соответствии с форматом выходных данных. Если несколько строк имеют одинаковую длину, выведите первую из них.

С векторами только начал учиться работать, не понимаю, как решить задачу:

```cpp
int longest_index = 0;
int current_index;
int siz = some_vector[longest_index].size();
for (int el : some_vector){
    int siz1 = some_vector[el].size();
    if (siz1 > siz){
        longest_index = some_vector[el];
    }
    current_index = current_index+1;
}
```

Буду очень благодарен, если поможете найти ошибки и объяснить их...

Comment: Индекс строки? Может быть, Вы имели в виду "длина строки"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут можно много чего поменять и исправить:

1. Вы изначально не проинициализировали переменную `current_index` никаким значением (хотя по идее оно должно равняться 0), но потом Вы пытаетесь прибавить к нему 1. Программа не понимает, как можно к чему-то неизвестному прибавить 1, и в лучшем случае распознает неизвестное как 0, а в худшем — отправит ошибку.
2. Конструкция типа `for (int x: vector)` будет искать **целочисленные значения в векторе**, а не **доставать их индексы**. Поскольку изначально вектор имеет только строковые величины, то данный цикл также не сработает.

С учётом всего вышеуказанного можно исправить код в примерно такое состояние:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int longest_index = 0;
    int current_index = 0;
    vector<string> some_vector = {"a", "ab", "abc"};
    int siz = some_vector[longest_index].size();
    for (string el : some_vector){
        int siz1 = el.size();
        if (siz1 > siz) {
            longest_index = current_index;
        }
        current_index = current_index+1;
    }
    cout << longest_index; // 2
}
```

Comment: Поскольку нужно найти индекс, то мне кажется, проще было бы сделать цикл по индексу, а не перебор коллекции. ```for (i=0; i<some_vector.size(); ++i)```

Comment: Не подскажете, как обработать строку , где длина всех элементов одинакова и нужно вывести первый элемент?

Comment: @Muffy пример выше удовлетворяет Вашему условию, потому что он в случае получения строки с максимальной (относительно предыдущих строк) длиной, НО при этом ранее уже были строки с такой же длиной, не будет перезаписывать строку. Например, если `some_vector = {"abc", "def", "ghi"}`, то тогда выведется `"abc"` как первая строка